Out-of-stock product details not showing in magento 2.4.5 GraphQl
out-of-stock products in productSearch query in magento 2.4.5 is not showing. The below query i am using --
{ products(filter: { category_id: { eq: "3" } }) { items { name sku url_key stock_status price_range { minimum_price { regular_price { value currency } } } } total_count page_info { page_size } } }
I want to show the outof-stock products in the productSearch query in magento 2.4.5. So from where I have to check this issue in magento 2.4.5 in code level.
